# Is it possible to define mutiple Hosts in SSH Config File?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I am new to this. I do not find if this question has been asked. I am using CYGWIN for Windows. I have already created a working shortcut for one of my sites to make the SSH easy. I have done the following

```
Host shortcut    
  HostName hostname.com
  User ubuntu    
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/path-to-file.pem"
```

Now I want to do this to another site with a long host name. Is it possible to define it in the same `config` file, or should it be done in new file? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be defined in the same `config`. It looks like the following example

```
Host shortcut
  HostName hostname.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/path-to-file.pem

Host shortcut2
  HostName hostname2.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/path-to-file2.pem
```